# django How to use Q and filter related_name in this case?

Tags: django, filter, model

I have a follow model like it:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fuser') #who is following
    follow = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ffollow') #who is followed
```

And then I want to get users by follow.

Case1: I want to find users that user_john and user_mark are both following.

```
users = User.objects.filter(Q(this_user_is_followed_by=user_john)
                            & Q(this_user_is_followed_by=user_mark))
```

Case2: Want to find users who is followed by user_john, but who is following user_mark.

```
users = User.objects.filter(Q(there_user_is_followed_by=user_john)
                            & Q(these_user_are_following=user_mark))
```

How to do that filter? Its too hard.

```
users = User.objects.filter(Q(ffollow__user=user)
                            & Q(ffollow__user=user_who_read))
```

will be answer to Case1.

But I cant be sure of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Case 1: I want to find users that `user_john` and `user_mark` are both following.

The first case should be resolved with *two* filters, since otherwise you are filtering on the *same* related object:

```
User.objects.filter(fuser__follow=user_john).filter(fuser__follow=user_mark)
```

> Case 2: Want to find users who is followed by `user_john`, but who is following `user_mark`.

```
User.objects.filter(fuser__follow=user_john, ffollow__user=user_mark)
```

Comment: You could use **`__in`** operator in the first case

Comment: @JPG: that will return the `User`s that follow `user_john` *or* (so one, or both) `user_mark`, not per se *both*.